# How to operate on batches in monger?

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

I'm querying a mongo collection from monger doing something like this:

```
(with-collection "my-collection" 
  (find {})
  (limit 1000)
  (batch-size 10))
```

I'm then iterating over the resulting cursor like this:

```
(doseq [item cursor]
  (do-something item))
```

It seems that monger is realizing the full 1000 items in the collection before iteration of the doseq loop starts. I'm looking for a way to start operating on the items in the batch as they are returned (ie: fetch 10 items, (do-something), fetch next 10 item, (do-something), etc).

Any tips for doing this would be appreciated!

Comment: What evidence you have that Monger is realising the full 1000 rather than lazily retrieving batches via the cursor?

Comment: There is a long pause before the first call to (do-something). At which point (do-something) is called 1000 times in very fast succession. I expected the first call to happen almost immediately with a slight delay after every 10 iterations.

Comment: Actually, false alarm. This is related to my repl. Im using fireplace.vim which collects all the output before printing it. When I run with 'lein run' I'm seeing the lazy evaluation as expected.